# Android Logcat Error Message: "file ... driverlist.txt not found!"

Tags: android, driver, logcat, nvidia

I got the following logcat error message:

```
file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
```

What does it mean? Can I get that file anywhere so this message disappears?

Comment: My device with Tegra 3 and Android 4.2.2 reports same too, but not for all apps. It means some apps try to do something.

Answer (score 1):

It's true... just about every tegra device gets this error...
but I was able to hide it by creating an empty file by myself:

in a terminal:

```
echo > /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt
```

you may need root access

Comment: Every Tegra, but error is generated by apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google "nvidia.NvCPLSvc", it's NVidia's power control application and just about every Android device with a Tegra chipset has the same logcat error.